# Minus in connected sum of manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, manifolds

I've stumbled across a thing $M \# (- M) $, where $M$ is a manifold and $\#$ obviously stands for connected sum. What does this minus mean? Than you for all your answers.

Comment: Orientation maybe?

Comment: It's $M$ with the opposite orientation.

Comment: A little more context might help. Also, have you formatted it correctly; is it, say, $M^{\sharp}(-M)$ instead?

Comment: It might be $\sharp$ (`$\sharp$`) and not $\#$ (`$\#$`).